# javascript for loop - how to get text before [i]

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, for-loop

I'm trying to create a parser to parse my coordinate data into json. The data is in a text file in a simple x,y format. I'm trying to get the the text before [i], is that possible with .split()?

Code:

```
function visualize()
{
    if(currDoc == null)
    {
        var location = window.prompt("Please enter the name of the dataset file, and make sure it is in the data directory. Current supported formats txt.");
        location = "data/" + location;
        jQuery.get(location, function(data) {
            data = data.replace(/\s/g, '');
            var length = data.length;
            var commaCount = 0;
            for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
            {
                if(data[i] == ",")
                {
                    commaCount += 1;
                    if(commaCount == 2)
                    {
                        //get text before [i]
                    }
                }
            }
        }, "text").fail(function(){ alert("File not found. Did you enter the file name correctly?") });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("A dataset is already visualized");
    }
}
```

Comment: whay not split the string with string.split()

Comment: @Teemu it will return only the last char not the text

Comment: It's not exactly clear what do you want to get from the input. Do you want each x and y pair or do you want to create longer strings based on some other rule?

Comment: please show sample input and expected results. See [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is delimited by commas like this `x1,y1,x2,y2,...,xn,yn` you can use the `split` function to split the string into tokens. Then you can iterate through them to collect whatever you need from the input.

For example if you need x and y pairs you would do something like this:

```
function visualize()
{
    if(currDoc == null)
    {
        var location = window.prompt("Please enter the name of the dataset file, and make sure it is in the data directory. Current supported formats txt.");
        location = "data/" + location;
        jQuery.get(location, function(data) {
            data = data.replace(/\s/g, '');

            // split the string 'x1,y1,...,xn,yn' into tokens ['x1', 'y1', ... 'xn', 'yn']
            var tokens = data.split(',');

            // iterate over all tokens using a step of 2 (i += 2)
            // Note: if you have an odd number of tokens the last one will be ignored
            // (this is by design because you are expecting x,y pairs)
            for(var i = 1; i < tokens.length; i += 2)
            {
                // print the (x,y) pair to the console
                console.log("New pair (" + tokens[i-1] + "," + tokens[i] + ")");
            }
        }, "text").fail(function(){ alert("File not found. Did you enter the file name correctly?") });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("A dataset is already visualized");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a pointer and a second array witch is filled by characters when you hit a comma join the array and you have the previews text, 
Does it make any sense.

```
function visualize()
{
    if(currDoc == null)
    {
        var location = window.prompt("Please enter the name of the dataset file, and make sure it is in the data directory. Current supported formats txt.");
        location = "data/" + location;
        jQuery.get(location, function(data) {
            data = data.replace(/\s/g, '');
            var length = data.length;
            var commaCount = 0;
            var charArray = [];

            for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
            {
                if(data[i] == ",")
                {
                    console.log('text' , charArray.join(''));
                    charArray = [];
                    commaCount += 1;
                    if(commaCount == 2)
                    {
                        //get text before [i]
                    }
                }else {
                 charArry.puch(data[i]);
                }
            }
        }, "text").fail(function(){ alert("File not found. Did you enter the file name correctly?") });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("A dataset is already visualized");
    }
}
```